# Scala Immutable maps Covariance

Tags: scala, covariance

Im trying to get a grasp of covariance and contravariance in Scala. I have set of classes like this  **Message1 and Message2 are subtypes of Message**

```
sealed trait Parser[T <: Message]{
  //... blah blah
}

class Parser1 extends Parser[Message1]{
}

class Parser2 extends Parser[Message2]{
}
```

Now I have anothe module ( a factory), that stores mappings in an immutable Map

```
var myMap = Map[String,Parser[Message]()
myMap += Map("Message1" -> new Parser1)
myMap += Map("Message2"-> new Parser2)
```

Now this doesnt compile. What am I missing?

This  is compile error I get

```
[error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,s.p.h.m.Parser1]
[error]  required: (String, s.p.h.m.Parser[c.s.m.Message])
[error]   myMap += Map("Message1" -> new Parser1)
```

Comment: Please provide working code. Is `Message1` a subtype of `Message`? `var myMap = Map[String,Parser]()` is not valid code because `Parser` takes a type argument.

Comment: Sorry about that..  Missed it when I replaced all proprietary names with generic ones..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have seen already that you need `++=` to add the entries of another map to the map, whereas `+` takes a single entry (a tuple of the key and value). If you want to keep the `var`, you need to make sure that `Parser` is covariant in `T` so that `Parser[Message1]` is considered a subtype of `Parser[Message]` (because the result of `+` will the be nearest supertype of the existing entries and the new entry, which then in this case will remain `Map[String,Parser[Message]]` and therefore it can be stored again in `myMap`):

```
trait Message; class Message1 extends Message; class Message2 extends Message

sealed trait Parser[+T <: Message]  // !
class Parser1 extends Parser[Message1]
class Parser2 extends Parser[Message2]

var myMap = Map.empty[String,Parser[Message]]
myMap += "Message1" -> new Parser1
myMap += "Message2"-> new Parser2
myMap ++= Map( "Message1b"-> new Parser1, "Message2b"-> new Parser2 )
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the error that you're getting? It doesn't look like you'd have any type errors here due to your `Parser` class hierarchy.

However, it looks like you're trying to mutate an immutable map, and that *would* cause an error. Also, you should be adding a *map pair* to the map rather than a *new map*. Try this instead:

```
val myMap = Map[String,Parser]()
val myMap1 = myMap + ("Message1" -> new Parser1)
val myMap2 = myMap1 + ("Message2" -> new Parser2)
```

If you really want to use `+=` instead of creating a new `val` for each update then you could use [`scala.collection.mutable.Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html) instead of the default (immutable) map type.